# How can I catch that a 404 for a route that does not exist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.0, and trying to write a code for returning a custom response for those requests to an unexistent route or to a route that does not match any of the registered endpoints.

According to what I've found and understood, there is this middleware that can handle the status code, so I'm doing as following

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(context => {

    if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 404) 
    {
        // Validates that is a redirection because it didn't
        // match any endpoint
    }

    return Task.CompletedTask;
});
```

My question is how can I determine whether that 404 corresponds to a redirection because it didn't find any matching endpoint? Because it also can refer that it does not find a specified resource for which the endpoint indeed exists, but the resource is not available, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1#usestatuscodepageswithreexecute) extension method:

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/page{0}");
```

Then, you create new controller to catch that event:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Page401()
    {
        // render Page401.cshtml
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Page404()
    {
        // render Page404.cshtml
        return View();
    }
}
```

Lastly, you create views for all of the status codes which you want to catch.

When you test with the url that doesn't exist, the page will render to the content of `Page404.cshtml` razor view.

Comment: How can I determine that the 404 it's a result of a non-matching endpoint, instead of a common 404 describing that reaches the endpoint but the requested resource was not found?